# Determinant of a special $n\times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Compute the determinant of the nun matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 &  1  & \ldots & 1 \\
1  &  2 & \ldots & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1  &   1       &\ldots & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

For $n=2$, I have$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 &  1   \\
1  &  2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then $det = 3$.

For $n=3$, we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 &  1 & 1\\
1  &  2 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then $det = 4$.

For $n=4$ again we have

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 &  1  & 1 & 1 \\
1  &  2 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
1  &   1  & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $det = 5$

How can I prove that the determinant of nun matrix is $n+1$.

Comment: Induction should work fine

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853981/find-the-eigenvalues-and-their-multiplicities-of-a-special-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A standard result (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) is $\det(I+AB) = \det(I+BA)$.

Since the matrix above can be written as $I+ e e^T$, where $e$ is a vector of ones, we have $\det(I+ e e^T) = \det(1+ e^T e) = 1+e^Te = n+1$.

Comment: I like your answer better even though we have the same idea. Mine is a bit of a over kill.

Comment: @user44197: Actually, I think yours is nicely minimal, mine is overkill...

Comment: If i want to use this result of wiki I need to prove first that nxn matrix is invertible

Comment: @Knight: $A=I$ here, which is invertible.

Comment: o yea yea sorry you are right

Comment: Eigenvalues of $I+A$ are $1$ plus eigenvalues of $A$. Also, non-zero eigenvalues of $XY$ is the same as the non-zero eigenvalues of $YX$. But frankly, I like copper.hat's answer better.

Comment: Invertibility is not needed anyway. The determinant identity holds.

Comment: @ copper.hat:  Just like the stuff they sell at the Walgreen's down on Telegraph:  *Nice*! +1!

Comment: @RobertLewis: Or the dollar stores :-).

Comment: @ copper.hat:  have you been in Walgreen's of late?  They have a whole product line branded with the name *Nice*; *Nice* peanuts, *Nice* water, *Nice* canned beans . . . as Vonnegut wrote, "Nice, nice, very nice . . . "

Comment: @RobertLewis: No, I completely missed the point of your earlier comment :-)!

Comment: @ copper.hat:  Oh yeah, Walgreen's has this new marketing strategy in which eveything is "nice".  Blandness will ever sell, apparently!  These remarks of course do not apply to your answer!

Comment: @RobertLewis: I was pointing out the marketing asymmetry to my kids the other day by noting that I have never seen a product advertised as 'completely unnatural'!

Answer (score 4):

Let $$v=(1,1,1,1...1)^T$$

Your matrix is $$
I + v v^T$$
This has $n-1$ eigenvalues equal to $1$ and one with value $n+1$. Hence the result.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way to do it:  note that the matrices in question are of the form $I + J$, where $J$ is the matrix every entry of which is $1$.  We have $J^2 = nJ$ by an easy calculation; thus the eigenvalues of $J$ are $0$ and $n$.  The eigenspace corresponding to $n$ is the one dimensional subspace spanned by the vector $v = (1, 1, ... , 1)^T$; since $\ker J$ consists of those vectors $w = (w_1, w_2, . . ., w_n)^T$ with $\sum_1^n w_i = 0$, the eigenspace corresponding to $0$ is of dimension $n - 1$; these observations imply the when $J$, being symmetric, is diagonalized one obtains a matrix with $n$ occurring at precisely one place on the diagonal, and zeroes everywhere else.  Thus we see that the multiplicity of $0$ as an eigenvalue is $n - 1$; that of $n$ is $1$.  Now use the fact that since $Jx = ax \Leftrightarrow (J + I)x = (a + 1)x$ to see that the eigenvalues of $I + J$ are $n + 1$, of multiplicity $1$, and $1$ of multiplicity $n - 1$.  Thus $\det (J + I)$, being the product of these eigenvalues, is $n + 1$.

Hope this helps.  Happy New Year,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Wow!  A plus one!  Just like the stuff they sell at Walgreen's, that's *nice*!  Thanks to whoever!  And a prosperous New Year to One and All!